# Can I have multiple Gmail accounts associated with Google+?

Tags: google-plus, google-account

I have two accounts that I wish to have associated with my Google+ profile. Meaning that I would like to be able to sign into either account, and have access to the *same* Google+ profile. Is this possible? And if yes, how?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No. Each Google+ account is tied to a Google Profile account, which can have only one primary email.

Comment: not that I don't believe you, but do you have a source from google for that ;)  Also, is this a feature that they might be looking into, or would that just be pure speculation ATM?

Comment: Check the revision history, it was an alternative solution but that doesn't work since the alt. email needs to be a non-Google account email. There's no other place to set another email address

Comment: As for your second question in the comment: It'd be pure speculation ( and I'd say it's unlikely they're going to add)

Comment: They should a lot of people have multiple email addresses, but typically just want 1 Google+ account.

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice work around listed here
http://socialtriggers.com/connect-gmail-google-plus/

Considering G+ allows you to add people to different circles (e.g. work and friends) then it makes sense that different emails (e.g. myname@gmail.com and myname@work.com) should both feed into a single G+ account.

They'll come to their senses soon enough.

Until then, we need work around it.

Comment: Can you add some information to your post beyond just a link? If nothing else, when that link stops working, there's nothing useful here.